# Unable to save the invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, error, paypal

I have set up a magento store with 5 stores for different sections of the charity. My problem exists in one store only 'fundraising'. The issue is this:

when a ticket is purchased through the store and paid for via PayPal standard, the transaction is not captured and no invoice is created. If I try to manually create the invoice I get the following error 'Unable to save the invoice'.

Please see contents of the log file below:

> 2015-05-05T11:20:34+00:00 ERR (3):
>   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'INV100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:

There is lots more the log is huge, I thought that line was the problem. I seriously stuck here so any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow your system tries to create an invoice id which already exists - as you might know.

The number is created from the content of `eav_entity_store`. So it might help to just raise the entry of `eav_entity_store` by 1.

`eav_entity_type` has the list of entity type ids. You need the id of invoice.

Then you need the website id and has to change the `increment_last_id`. But PLEASE make a backup before.

And btw, I expect the current value to be `100000000`

Comment: You were right I found the store id, looked up the last used invoice id and raised it by one in the relevant field you sir are a legend!

Comment: updated the answer